# Combine observations for same ID and year into a single row as counting variables

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata in the following structure:

| ID | Year | Car | Origin_of_Company | City_of_Company | Index_of_Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | Ford | Illinois | Chicago | Nasdaq |
| 1 | 2022 | Ford | Illinois | Chicago | Nasdaq |
| 1 | 2022 | Chevy | Illinois | Chicago | Nasdaq |
| 1 | 2019 | BMW | Illinois | Chicago | Dow_Jones |
| 2 | 2017 | Ford | Michigan | Detroit | Dow_Jones |
| 2 | 2017 | BMW | Michigan | Detroit | Dow_Jones |
| 2 | 2017 | Ford | Michigan | Detroit | Dow_Jones |

Now I want to combine all observations for Car per ID and Year into one single row while keeping the year-fixed and ID-fixed data (e.g., Origin_of_Company, City_of_Company, Index_of_Company). Since the same Car sometimes occurs more times per year and ID, I want to construct the different Cars as counting variables.
So the result should look like this:

| ID | Year | Ford | Chevy | BMW | Origin_of_Company | City_of_Company | Index_of_Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 2 | 1 | 0 | Illinois | Chicago | Nasdaq |
| 1 | 2019 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Illinois | Chicago | Dow_Jones |
| 2 | 2017 | 2 | 0 | 1 | Michigan | Detroit | Dow_Jones |

Is this possible in Stata or is it to much of a mixture of the long and wide format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id int year str5 car
1 2022 "Ford" 
1 2022 "Chevy"
1 2019 "BMW"  
2 2017 "Ford" 
2 2017 "BMW"  
end

encode car, gen(CAR)

reshape wide CAR , i(id year) j(car) string 

foreach v of var CAR* { 
    replace `v' = !missing(`v')
} 

rename CAR* * 
label drop CAR 

list 

     +--------------------------------+
     | id   year   BMW   Chevy   Ford |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |  1   2019     1       0      0 |
  2. |  1   2022     0       1      1 |
  3. |  2   2017     1       0      1 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Not all car names will be legal variable names, so see `help strtoname()` if necessary.

EDIT Revised version given changes in question.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id int year str5 car str8 origin_of_company str7 city_of_company str9 index_of_company
1 2022 "Ford"  "Illinois" "Chicago" "Nasdaq"   
1 2022 "Ford"  "Illinois" "Chicago" "Nasdaq"   
1 2022 "Chevy" "Illinois" "Chicago" "Nasdaq"   
1 2019 "BMW"   "Illinois" "Chicago" "Dow_Jones"
2 2017 "Ford"  "Michigan" "Detroit" "Dow_Jones"
2 2017 "BMW"   "Michigan" "Detroit" "Dow_Jones"
2 2017 "Ford"  "Michigan" "Detroit" "Dow_Jones"
end

contract *, freq(CAR)
replace car = strtoname(car)
reshape wide CAR, i(id year) j(car) string
recode CAR* (.=0)
rename CAR* *

list 

     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   year   BMW   Chevy   Ford   origin~y   city_o~y   index_o~y |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   2019     1       0      0   Illinois    Chicago   Dow_Jones |
  2. |  1   2022     0       1      2   Illinois    Chicago      Nasdaq |
  3. |  2   2017     1       0      2   Michigan    Detroit   Dow_Jones |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The first line could be `gen CAR = 1`. I also contribute a solution, which is almost the same as Nick's but pays attention to the case an ID may have more than 1 car of the same brand.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether some IDs have more than 1 car of the same brand?

The code below records the dummy variables (for cars) but could be extended to the counting variables if you may want it. If so, just use: `recode Count* (.=0)` at the third line.

```
contract *, freq(Count) nomiss
reshape wide Count, i(id year) j(car) string

recode Count* (.=0) (else = 1)
ren Count* *
```

Comment: That’s characteristically neat.